# On Hold policy for sites that are PRIMARILY opinion based

Tags: discussion, on-hold

The Workplace seems like one example of a site that is primarily asking opinion bases questions: "way to professionaly quit a job?", etc.  I noticed that a lot of questions are getting flagged as on-hold in that site.  Why?  These are not questions with clear concise answers like "Why does this fail << codesample >>?"

Comment: The Workplace is welcoming to _some_ subjective questions, sure, but a far cry from being _primarily_ opinion based.

Comment: Even if The Workplace isn't considered, it's undeniable that some other betas(looking at you, [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)) are *at least* implicitly inviting opinion-based questions. The question asks about "sites **like** TW", not exclusively that one.

Comment: Related discussions on Meta.Workplace: [Is Workplace going to follow the same life cycle as other SE sites for subjective questions?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/144), [Does this site need a “back it up” rule?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5), [How do we define Constructive on this site?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/261).

Comment: And of course there's the canonical post [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: @Geobits I thought of Soft Rec just like you, until I happened to stumble upon [a bunch of their meta posts / guidelines](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13855775#13855775). Guess what? I changed my mind since

Comment: @gnat They do seem to have it worked out on meta. Hopefully it works out the way on the main site. It definitely seems to *flex* the SE model, or at least many users may see it that way. I was primarily pointing out that the answers/comments here seemed fixated on TW exclusively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But there are still valid reasons to put questions on hold. On Workplace, where I'm a member, they often get duplicates. Things like "How do I deal with this coworker" or "how to I ask for a raise", etc.

So, just because the material is often subjective, does not mean that we should preclude closures.

And yes, I have to echo Yannis - Workplace is not an opinion-based site. That is an oversimplification. It is perhaps more political and rooted in experiences, than say - Mathematica or ServerFault.

Answer (score 4):

> I noticed that a lot of questions are getting flagged as on-hold in that site. Why?

We get people asking "Dear Workplace, what should I do?" and who come without actual problems of any sort.

Many of the questions which get closed are questions which at root cause are not actually questions but rather "tell me what to do" or "what advice do you have!" or "what are some tips for life."

These are no different than "gimme teh codez."

> These are not questions with clear concise answers like "Why does this fail << codesample >>?"

There are a lot of questions where you CAN have very good answers. The thing is, you have to have a tangible question to answer.

There are many questions there which are very answerable.

*Source: I have nearly 20k rep on Workplace.*

---

I should add that for more subjective sites you [really need different standards for quality](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1627/2322) for answers. A similar post could exist for questions, and in fact, we've been working on a blog post for that, I'll have to see if I can find it.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from questions that have a clear, identifiable problem, we want questions that can be answered with facts, references, and specific expertise. In short, a question can have answers with opinions, but those opinions should be backed up with something that shows that you know what you're talking about.

The Workplace put in place [The Back It Up Principle](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/faq-proposal-back-it-up-and-dont-repeat-others) which states that opinions should be backed with a reference or with experiences that happened to you personally. These guidelines are based on the information learned from [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), which tells us that answers to subjective questions should explain *why* and *how*.  Typically, these answers shouldn't be short but should instead be long enough to give a future reader enough information to make a good decision.

The goal of The Workplace is to become a resource of factual knowledge or knowledge based on expertise. In order to do that, we sometimes must exclude certain questions that would inhibit this goal.

If you do have a question that doesn't fit the Q&A format, we have [The Water Cooler Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler). There are regulars who hang out there who enjoy helping others with problems that can't necessarily fit on the main site. Hope this helps!